# How to use ansible with domain accounts on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-domain, ansible

I am having issues getting ansible to be able to use domain accounts on windows machines. It tells me that the credentials are not recognized (the same error when you type the wrong password in). It works fine when I try to use local accounts though.

My inventory looks like this:

`hostname:
            public_ipv4_cidr: .....
            .....
            ansible_connection: winrm
            ansible_user: DOMAIN\user`:

the command i use to run my playbook is:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/ playbook.yml -k
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try 2 things:

1. Add `ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm` in your inventory provided that NTLM is allowed/enabled in your windows environment
2. To permanently fix this issue, configure kerberos in Ansible host
   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#kerberos